# How to bind post request to a model in Laravel 5

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

How do I bind my post request to a model in routes.php?

```
    Route::post('/api/users/validate', 'UserController@validate'); //Want to 
assign a model to this post request
```

Below is the model that I have created

VUser.php

```
Class VUser extends Model{
protected userName;
protected password;
}
```

UserController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\VUser;

class VUserController extends Controller{
public function validate(VUser $u){
return "success";
}
}
```

My Ajax Request

```
$scope.VUser={'userName' : $scope.userName, 'password': $scope.password};

$http.post('/api/users/validate', {'VUser': $scope.VUser}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {               
alert("success");
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
alert ("error");
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: run `php artisan route:list` this command in terminal and give your output line for that route...!

Answer (score 0):

There is whole topic of resource controllers information for Laravel at http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

If this is too much for you then in your case you can also define single route with URL param

```
Route::post('/api/users/{user}/validate', 'UserController@validate');
```

Now find your RouteServiceProvider and define the binding for user like below. After that you can use `User $user` in each of the controller functions where {user} is in.

```
$router->model('user', 'App\User');
```

You also need to change your AngularJS code so the post goes to the url `/api/users/XX/validate` where XX is your user ID in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to bind model to my post request now. Only issue am I facing now is all properties of my model is null in my validate method. `public function validate(VUser $u){
dd($u);
}`